# I'm trying to installing scandipwa with npx and i just found error in NPM packages

Tags: npm, node-modules, npm-install

npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /var/www/html/scandi_app/my-app/scandi-app/node_modules/node-sass
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node scripts/build.js
npm ERR! Building: /usr/local/bin/node /var/www/html/scandi_app/my-app/scandi-app/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
npm ERR! make: Entering directory '/var/www/html/scandi_app/my-app/scandi-app/node_modules/node-sass/build'
....

100s lines of code

Answer (score -1):

I was locking inside the yarn.lock and the node sass version is node-sass@^4.14.1: and you can follow this table to see the node version you should use

https://i.stack.imgur.com/o02R3.png

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).